# This code finds a single letter and checks if its in the word thats inputted. How can I have the letter I am searching for as a PARAMETER?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def count_letter(letter):
    a = input("whats the word: ")
    count = 0

    for i in a:
       if i == letter:
        count += 1
    return count


print(count_letter("e"))
```

How can I have the letter I am searching for as a PARAMETER in the function. So the function should take both the string and the letter to search for and then count how many times it occurs.

Comment: You already have the letter as a parameter. Do you want the word to be a parameter too? Is it just that you don't know how to add a second parameter to a Python function?

Comment: FWIW, you can do the count more easily like this: `return sum(i == letter for i in a)`

Answer (score 0):

The function "count_letter" already has a parameter called "letter". If you are looking for scripting and run the program say like this

```
$ python my_prog.py e
```

and receive the same result as you had previously you can use the standard library modules called `sys` or `argparse`.

```
import sys

def count_letter(letter):
    a = input("whats the word: ")
    count = 0

    for i in a:
       if i == letter:
        count += 1
    return count

print(count_letter(sys.argv[1]))
```

For more details: [Writing scripts: `sys` and `argparse` - Object-Oriented Programming in Python](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Useful_Libraries.html#writing-scripts-sys-and-argparse)